Azure Function debug locally not showing logs every other run
I'm debugging an Azure Function locally. I'm using Microsoft Logging with dependency injection, which usually works fine. I have a strange phenomenon however where my function won't show logs every other run.
If i run the function the first time, there are no logs.
Running it the second time will show logs.
The third time, no logs.
etc.
Does anybody know what can be causing this hugely annoying behavior?
It's got nothing to do with settings (i recon) because it works/doesn't work with the same settings. It's just every other run.
Thanks
Host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "NotificationFunctions": "Debug",
      "DataLayer": "Debug",
      "ServiceLayer": "Debug",
      "Function": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Trace;Request"
      },
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "maxMessageBatchSize": 20
    }
  }
}

Startup.cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace NotificationFunctions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // ...
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
        }

        private static IConfigurationRoot InitializeConfiguration(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile($"local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
            return configuration;
        }
    }
}


What is the version of your Function App? Plaese refer this SOthread

@Harshitha it's .NET 6 Azure Functios Version v4
